# Webcomic with a protagonist who can walk through walls

Tags: story-identification, webcomics, black-hole

I have been trying to recall an English webcomic where the protagonist had the power of walking through walls.

In one story, there was a sentient miniature black hole devouring everything. The protagonist controls the situation by getting the black hole to 'eat' a Klein bottle, effectively capturing it 'inside'.

Thanks for the help!